# How to test a call to setContentView?

Tags: android, unit-testing, layout, android-activity

How do I write a unit test to determine that the layout used in `setContentView(int layoutId)` has been called and corresponds to the proper layout for a given activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Calculon](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/introducing-calculon-a-java-dsl-for-android-activity-testing/). There is a simple way to do what you want.